# Catch Onesignal data in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, push-notification, onesignal

I have simple question. I am using Onesignal in laravel. I send notification like that:

```
OneSignal::sendNotificationToAll(
    "Some Message", 
    $url = "orders", 
    $data =  null,
    $buttons = null, 
    $schedule = null
);
```

In javascript code I run that:

```
<script>
var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];

OneSignal.push(function() {
    OneSignal.init({
        appId: "e7a62ea9-94e4-437c-a3cd-1a1a16408867",
    });
});
```

when I click received notification, it redirects me to provided $url. Now how can I use $data? I send $data with that notification but how can I catch it in javascript when I click notification?

Answer (score 0):

```
    OneSignal.on('notificationDisplay',function (e){
      /*your code*/
    }
```

is what you need.

`e` gives you the title, content, data,...